# Installing Windows 7 on a 4TB Hard Disk (not detecting above 2TB)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, gpt

I have a SeaGate Hard Disk (with 4TB capacity) which has the code number **ST4000VX000-1F4168** (Surveillance HDD). I am trying to install Windows 7 in it and Windows 7 only detects 2TB capacity and not 4TB.

So, I followed the details explained in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2604034), I connected the 4TB Hard Disk to another computer as a secondary HDD.Then followed the details from the link above to make it **GPT**. Then the computer detected the 4TB. So I created 4 partitions (1TB each). Then connected the 4TB HDD back to the original computer and this time Windows 7 says it cannot install Windows on GPT partitions.

Then I followed the instructions on [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQf9YqbD8WI). This cleared the GPT partitions and removed all four partitions created. I was able to install Windows 7 but it could not be partitioned into four drives.

What I like to know is how to install Windows 7 on 4TB HDD (partition into four drives)? If I install Windows 10 instead of Windows 7, will it detect 4TB and will I be able to partition into four drives and install Windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need **a motherboard that support UEFI**! If you already have such a motherboard, then **Windows OS must be 64-bit** in order to be successfully installed on the 4 TB HDD *(regardless of the OS version itself)*. Finally, you must start Windows setup in UEFI mode.

If you don't have these specific requirements, you won't be able to use the full capacity with the 4 TB HDD as a boot/primary drive. However, non-UEFI mobos can use massive HDDs ***(above 2TB, initialized in GPT)***  as secondary storage drives. This means that you should be able to access the full capacity if you use a different HDD or SSD for booting the operating system. Your other option would be to upgrade the motherboard to a UEFI-based one.

Comment: 1 note: 64Bit is required for Vista and Win7. Since Win8, also the 32Bit Windows supports UEFI boot.

Comment: [@SuperSoph_WD](http://superuser.com/users/512177/supersoph-wd) and [@magicandre1981](http://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) - My motherboard is **DH55HC**. In the BIOS it did have an option to enable UEFI. I enabled it and still the same result. No changes. Does my Motherboard support UEFI?

Comment: @CodenameK at start where the BIOS info are shown, look if you have an option to open a boot manager and select here UEFI boot for the DVD/flash drive with the setup files of Windows.

Comment: [@magicandre1981](http://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) - It worked. I created a UEFI bootable USB drive with Windows setup in it. And then set the motherboard from BIOS to load from USB. This did the trick. Thanks for your help. Thanks to you too [@SuperSoph_WD](http://superuser.com/users/512177/supersoph-wd).

Comment: There are a couple of tools to add EFI capabilities to an old "real" BIOS -- DUET and Clover. The first is intended as a developer's tool and the second is primarily a Hackintosh boot loader, so neither is easy to use for something like the stated situation. Fortunately, most PCs sold since 2011 have EFIs, not old-style BIOSes. I mention this only for completeness and the benefit of future readers, since Codename K seems to have gotten it to work and doesn't need this information.